# Unable to chart a datatable because of MySQL datetime

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C# in VS2010 and trying to use MS Chart Control to draw graphs by binding data from a Datatable. The error I had is that MySQL datetime is not supported by Chart Control. However, would like to have some advice on this.

Prior to the graphs, I use MySQL database to fill the datatable and it works fine like below.

```
string cmdstring = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn);
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dtable);
```

Then, after that I tried to use the data inside to draw a chart as follows:

```
 chart1.DataSource = dbtables[Group1.Text];
 chart1.Series.Add(Group1.Text);
 chart1.Series[Group1.Text].XValueMember = "datetime";
 chart1.Series[Group1.Text].YValueMembers = "datatype";
 chart1.DataBind(); /// Line Error
```

It turns out to have error where I commented. I understand from reading other solutions that maybe this can be fixed by using a query line that converts the datetime simultaneously. However, I'm trying to extract different structures of tables from MySQL database - thus, using a more general function to "fill" Datatables. Hope that I'm clear in my question and for advice on how to bind the data to the charts properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you assign the datasource of your chart to the DataTable you should ammend the format of your date column in the datatable.

You can amend the date to a custom format quite easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Would like to find out how to amend the date? I'm new to C# too actually, I previously use python and there's a way to map a function like Datetime.Parse to a list quite easily. Is there such a method for C#? If not, I'm also not sure how to access a DataColumn...Thanks!